# Solution for An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting (Compiler Error) "Error    CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property ". My code is mentioned below. Can please anyone assist me how to fix this issue.

```
 private static Task<string> SendPasswordResetVerificationCode(string email)
    {
        string randomVerificationCode = new Random().Next(1000, 9999).ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

        ////send verification code to given email
        if (email != null)
        {
            SendEmail(email, randomVerificationCode);
            return Task.FromResult("VerificationCode Sent");
        }

        return Task.FromResult("VerificationCode Sent");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sends an email for verification code
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="email">email address that will receive verification code</param>
    /// <param name="verificationCode">verification code</param>
    private void SendEmail(string email, string verificationCode)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                    SmtpClient smtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
                    mail.From = new MailAddress("v@gmail.com");
                    mail.To.Add(email);
                    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    mail.Subject = "Verification Code";
                     mail.Body = verificationCode;
                    smtpServer.Port = 587;

                    smtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    smtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
                    smtpServer.Send(mail);
                    mail.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Utilities.Logging.LogManager.Write(ex);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: You need to post more info... Which line is giving you the error?

Comment: does your method have to be static?
Try removing the static access modifier.

Comment: Where are you encountering the exception?  Please inspect the exception you're seeing and provide additional information.

Comment: This is a compiler error, correct?
BTW, based on your conditional logic you should return Task.FromResult("VerificationCode Sent"); just once outside of your if statement

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into the two methods that you already having, ie., `SendPasswordResetVerificationCode` and `SendEmail`, among them SendEmail is instance method and the first one is a static method. Now take a look into the error message. it's clear enough, as it says `object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property` when you call `SendEmail` from the static method.

So the fix is quick and simple change `SendEmail` as a static method as well. So the definition would be like the following:

```
private static void SendEmail(string email, string verificationCode)
{    
    // code here
}
```

Note : if you don't have any specific reason for `SendPasswordResetVerificationCode` to be static means you can remove static from the signature as well without changing the signature of the `SendEmail` but the actual call should be with a reference object